# Is it possible to run a script on my frontend, in the background, that'll update a variable every few minutes?

Tags: javascript, fetch, background-process

I have a form with a drop down select input field.
this select field's options should ideally be up to date with the backend.

I have a script in the backend which updates a list of options every 5 minutes.

As an initial trivial solution I've added an 'on focus' event listener to the select filed which fires a fetch request and updates the drop down with the returned list.

This off course introduces a small delay, and is overall unpleasant to use when I have menus that react in dependence to the first drop down.

Is there a way to run a script on the frontend background that'll fetch the options to a variable and update the drop down every few minutes?

(I'm using vanilla JS)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Look into `setInterval`.

Comment: You can use ```setInterval``` but you will need to make sure you cleanup after it is no longer needed as this could cause serious memory leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this to update every 10 seconds:

```
function getOptions(){
  setInterval(async function(){
    const response = await fetch(/*whatever you want to fetch*/);  
    const options = await response.text();
    /*use the data here*/
  }, 10000);
}
```

You could also do a function which fires itself when it is done fetching the data using fetch().then() which I think is to be preferred here.

`fetch()` can use `.then()`, `.catch()` and `.finally()` so you could run the function again at `.finally()`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very helpful! works perfectly!

about the function firing itself in this scenario, forgive my ignorance, but wouldn't it result in a stack overflow? sorry I'm quite new to FE development

Comment: Made the answer a little more detailed. Since the fetch requires some time to complete, it would be fine and you're handing any errors in `.catch()` too.